# Make canonical URL in document HEAD absolute

Tags: 8, uri

I have a requirement to use absolute URLs for the canonical URL element generated by Drupal 8.

`hook_page_attachments_alter` doesn't seem to have access the HTML element. Is there any other way I can access it?

Answer (score 3):

True, for nodes you can't use `hook_page_attachments_alter`. You have to use [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter/8.2.x)!

And very likely you also find all of them in the end in `hook_preprocess_html`.

Here's how I got it working:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_node_view_alter(array &$build, Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display) {
  if (isset($build['#attached']['html_head_link'])) {
    foreach ($build['#attached']['html_head_link'] as $key => $head) {
      if ((isset($head[0]['rel']) ? $head[0]['rel'] : FALSE) == 'canonical') {

        $url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('<current>', [], ['absolute' => 'true'])
          ->toString();

        $build['#attached']['html_head_link'][$key][0]['href'] = $url;
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Source: [How to remove specific meta-tag from header section of page?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/264280/15055)

---

Alternatively you can use [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag). All you have to do is to set the `[node:url:absolute]` token into the Canonical URL form field in the Advanced section of the Metatag configuration for all Content.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

And only then, all of sudden, they become available to be preprocessed in [`hook_page_attachments_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments_alter/8.2.x). There I removed their trailing slash which gets added by default.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_attachments_alter().
 */
function MYTHEME/MYMODULE_page_attachments_alter(array &$attachments) {

  // Remove trailing slash from canonicals.
  foreach ($attachments['#attached']['html_head'] as $key => $head) {

    if ((isset($head[1]) ? $head[1] : FALSE) == 'canonical_url') {

      $href = isset($head[0]['#attributes']['href']) ? $head[0]['#attributes']['href'] : FALSE;

      if ($href) {
        $attachments['#attached']['html_head'][$key][0]['#attributes']['href'] = rtrim($href, '/');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's not fun, but entirely necessary to override a canonical URL meta tag on a node. Thanks for posting this solution!