# How to load absolute CSS and JS assets

Tags: 8, theming, cdn

I would like to load CSS and JS from https://static.example.com . The typical page contains:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/default/files/css/css__wBfhyL83sORKzo__AgHv4HOGuOoSbIzIaa4clq9PXs.css?pik02l" media="all" />
```

and contains similar entries for JS.  I would like to add https://static.example.com to the front of the `href="URL"` for both CSS and JS.

I'm am aware that this can be done with a contrib module.  I would like to **find a hook** or some other way to add this to my custom module.

Comment: Dis you try adding to your libraries.yml?

Answer (score 1):

Even though you don't want to use a contrib module I will recommend the [CDN module](https://www.drupal.org/project/cdn) anyways. It does what you want, but if you don't want to use it you can still look at how they do it.

They define a lot of services, but the most interesting one is this one:

```
cdn.file_url_generator:
    class: Drupal\cdn\File\FileUrlGenerator
    arguments: ['@app.root', '@file_system', '@stream_wrapper_manager', '@request_stack', '@private_key', '@cdn.settings']
```

The class `FileUrlGenerator` then does checks for files to determine if they should be rewritten and rewrites them.

Answer (score 0):

These are aggregated assets, so you need to find out how they get added there in the first place. Then you can alter them most likely via [`hook_page_attachments_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments_alter/8.2.x). Similar to [Make canonical URL in document HEAD absolute](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/263077/15055).

Problematic about this approach is that these assets should are aggregated with that cryptic hash in their name *per environment*. So you need to switch off your custom module everywhere else except on the live instance.