# metatag_hreflang outputting extra hreflang tags

Tags: meta-tags

I need to generate hreflang tags in my website and I've installed metatag_hreflang submodule (belongs to metatag module)

It's now outputting the following

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://domain.com/ca/en/home" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="https://domain.com/ca/fr/home" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-CA" href="https://domain.com/ca/en" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr-CA" href="https://domain.com/ca/fr" />
```

I don't need the extra "en" or "fr" I've already defined it at the bottom such as en-CA and fr-CA.

how do I get rid of the first 2 lines that it's outputting. This is not happening on other pages, it's only happening on the Homepage.

Comment: Is it possible that the first two come from core and the other two from the module?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I overwrite meta tags?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/181846/how-do-i-overwrite-meta-tags)